# What does DX mean in remastered games?

Tags: terminology

Today, a remake of the original Pokemon Mystery Dungeon game was announced, called *Pokemon Mystery Dungeon: Rescue Team DX*.

This got me thinking about how I've also seen the "DX" title in lots of other remade or remastered games, including *Pokken Tournament DX*, *Tetris DX*, and *Link's Awakening DX*, but have no idea what the acronym means and have never seen it used for any media other than games.

So, my question: what does DX actually stand for, and how/when did it become a term meant to indicate remade or remastered video games? Googling only came up with "Deus Ex" or "Diagnosis" as possible acronyms, and neither of those make much sense.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

When "DX" is used in this context, it is short for "Deluxe". This was confirmed on [Zelda.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20050313081801/http://www.zelda.com/universe/game/awakening/faq.jsp) back when Link's Awakening DX first came out.

> **What does "DX" stand for?**
>
> DX stands for "Deluxe."

As for the origin of the term in this context, it appears to have started with a small set of Game Boy games that were being re-released for the Game Boy Color around 1998 and 1999. These were known as the [Game Boy Color DX Series](https://www.mobygames.com/game-group/game-boy-color-dx-series).

It is not as common as terms like "HD" or "Remaster", but it is very similar in its usage.